# MP3s served to XBox 360 on FreeBSD?

Tags: music, network-shares, xbox360, freebsd

My music library lives on my FreeBSD server, mostly in "Apple Lossless" M4A format, but with MP3s mixed in. My laptop accesses it via AFP.

What can I use on FreeBSD to share the music with my XBox 360?

Comment: Someone on IRC suggested "Coherence" - http://coherence.beebits.net/

Answer (score 1):

I used FUPPES for this for a while:

Since it's not under ports, here's my notes from when I did it, these were almost all installed using the ports system w/ the default settings.

- Install Subversion (svn) or make sure it's already on your system
- FUPPES installation steps

  - install lame
  - install ffmpeg

    - make sure xvid is checked
    - installed vorbis automatically
  - install taglib - extracts id3 tags and such from media files - needed to support virtual folders
  - install ImageMagik - image scaling and support
  - install sqlite3
  - install mpeg4ip - extracts metadata from mpeg4's (installed a LOT of extra packages I wasn't too keen about)
  - install libuuid (e2fsprogs-libuuid) - needed for XBOX 360 since it's picky about UUIDs
  - install libiconv - charset converter (NOT just iconv!)
- use the steps below to download the fuppes sources and build/install it:

```
$ svn co https://fuppes.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/fuppes/trunk fuppes

$ cd fuppes/

$ autoreconf -vfi

$ ./configure --enable-video-transcoding --with-lame-dir=/usr/local/include LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib

$ make

$ build fuppes

$ install fuppes
```

LDFLAGS was needed in the configure step because libmp4v2 could not be found without it when I did it.

Then go here for how to configure/use it: http://falz.net/xboxstreaming

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [FUPPES](http://fuppes.ulrich-voelkel.de/features/) media server or [uShare](http://ushare.geexbox.org/).